# How do we design schema for user settings table for postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, schema

How do we design schema for user settings/preferences table in a sql database like postgresql?

I am interested to know the proper way to design the schema of `users_setting` table where users are able to modify their settings. This seems to be a 1-to-1 relationship because each row of `users` table corresponds to a single row in the `users_setting` table

so this is like a 1-to-1 table relation between `users` and `users_setting`. Is this the wrong way to do this? I have searched online and could not really find any useful example schemas where users manage their settings. So here i am asking this question. I am certain this will help many people also

Here is what my current design looks like

[image]

```
DROP TABLE if exists users cascade;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "users";
DROP SEQUENCE IF EXISTS users_id_seq;
CREATE SEQUENCE users_id_seq INCREMENT 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 CACHE 1;

CREATE TABLE "public"."users" (
    "id" bigint DEFAULT nextval('users_id_seq') NOT NULL,
    "email" text NOT NULL,
    "password" text NOT NULL,
    "full_name" text NOT NULL,
    "status" text NOT NULL,
    "is_verified" boolean NOT NULL,
    "role" text NOT NULL,
    "created_at" timestamptz NOT NULL,
    "updated_at" timestamptz NOT NULL,
    "verified_at" timestamptz NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "users_email_key" UNIQUE ("email"),
    CONSTRAINT "users_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
) WITH (oids = false);

DROP TABLE if exists users_setting cascade;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "users_setting";
DROP SEQUENCE IF EXISTS users_setting_id_seq;
CREATE SEQUENCE users_setting_id_seq INCREMENT 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 CACHE 1;

CREATE TABLE "public"."users_setting" (
    "id" bigint DEFAULT nextval('users_setting_id_seq') NOT NULL,
    "default_currency" text NOT NULL,
    "default_timezone" text NOT NULL,
    "default_notification_method" text NOT NULL,
    "default_source" text NOT NULL,
    "default_cooldown" integer NOT NULL,
    "updated_at" timestamptz NOT NULL,
    "user_id" bigint,
    CONSTRAINT "users_setting_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
) WITH (oids = false);


ALTER TABLE ONLY "public"."users_setting" ADD CONSTRAINT "users_setting_user_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES "users"(id) NOT DEFERRABLE;

begin transaction;

INSERT INTO "users" ("id", "email", "password", "full_name", "status", "is_verified", "role", "created_at", "updated_at", "verified_at") VALUES
(1, 'users1@email.com', 'password', 'users1',   'active',   '1', 'superuser', '2022-07-05 01:05:50.22384+00',   '0001-01-01 00:00:00+00',   '2022-07-11 14:10:26.615722+00'),
(2, 'users2@email.com', 'password', 'users2', 'active', '0', 'user', '2022-07-05 01:05:50.22384+00',    '0001-01-01 00:00:00+00',   '2022-07-11 14:10:26.615722+00');

INSERT INTO "users_setting" ("id", "default_currency", "default_timezone", "default_notification_method", "default_source", "default_cooldown", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES
(1, 'usd', 'utc', 'email',  'google',   300, '2022-07-13 01:05:50.22384+00', 2),
(2, 'usd', 'utc', 'sms',    'yahoo',    600, '2022-07-14 01:05:50.22384+00',    2);

commit;
```

so lets say i want to return a single row where a users.email is `users1@email.com` for example, here is query i can run

```
select * from users, users_setting where users.id = users_setting.user_id AND users.email = 'users1@email.com';
```

```
id  email               password    full_name   status  is_verified role    created_at  updated_at  verified_at id  default_currency    default_timezone    default_notification_method default_source  default_cooldown    updated_at  user_id
1   users1@email.com    password    users1  active  1   superuser   2022-07-05 01:05:50.22384+00    0001-01-01 00:00:00+00  2022-07-11 14:10:26.615722+00   1   usd utc email   google  300 2022-07-13 01:05:50.22384+00    1
```

i can have a single table for this but the table will get really long row-wise as i add more and more thing. user settings is just one, there are other tables similar to this. So will be great to know how to design a situation like this properly

Comment: AFAIK if you have one to one relation between 2 table then there is no point to keep 2 tables generally. So better keep it in a single table

Comment: the user settings can grow depending on the app...for example i can have notification settings, which is tied to each user...i mean the table will have so many columns..it will almost be a complete mess...i haven't seen tables with huge number of columns publicly, so what are people doing? any example schema that used same table for user settings/preferences? will like to see please

Comment: All the settings you've shown us look fine to have in the user table. As for some other class of settings you haven't shown us, what can we say about those, having not seen them?

Comment: i mentioned there can be notification settings...again am asking how people are doing this; are people having tables with like 50 columns? because at that rate that can happen...many apps have user settings...where can i see schema design for these publicly? all these publicly shared schemas i do not see this scenario

Answer (score 2):

In your case a JSON could do the job:

```
ALTER TABLE public.users ADD user_settings jsonb NULL;
```

Update of settings will be something like:

```
UPDATE users
SET user_settings = '{"default_currency": "usd", "default_timezone" : "utc"}'
WHERE id = 1;
```

And select:

```
select * from users WHERE id  = 1;
```

You will find:
[image]

Also consider in Postgresql you can index a JSON, for example to query on a particular setting. Se here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING
Specific:

> Still, with appropriate use of expression indexes, the above query can
> use an index. If querying for particular items within the "tags" key
> is common, defining an index like this may be worthwhile:
>
> CREATE INDEX idxgintags ON api USING GIN ((jdoc -> 'tags'));

Comment: i will like to avoid JSON; how were people doing this before JSON was supported?

Comment: With no JSON you could use a table attribute value.. Many records for each user.

Comment: can i see what that will look like? you can put like answer 2 and state how that will look like..ok to keep the json option for others that may be helpful to..thanks

Comment: am taking a serious look at your JSON approach; do you have references.sources of people using this approach i can read up on more? i want to use something a serious app uses also...so am sure others are using it..but i think the JSON approach looks promising

Comment: No, I have used it internally, so I have no way to share it. Also: added a solution with separated table.

Comment: so you chose the JSON solution? didn't you research this before using it? how has it worked out so far since using it?

Comment: what software did you create the screenshot from? https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnw2X.png

Comment: Honestly I don't even remember when I started using JSON. Actually I use it a lot to map custom datatype and map them to c# classes..

Comment: Screenshot is from Dbeaver: https://dbeaver.io/

Comment: how has using JSON on postgresql worked out so far since using it? works fine with millions of rows?

Comment: In my experience? It works fine, but with few considerations. Since it can be very big I would not use in a table with tons of insert and update per second. For the same reason I would not use a big binary field or text. Also you must be careful with indexes. And querying the json, can be expensive in cpu terms. But for this scenario, settings, it fits perfectly.

Comment: well for user settings..if one have millions of users...thousands can update their settings at same time

Comment: In any case, with thousands update, any solution will require proper DB sizing.. And partitions are a must.

Comment: what about scaling vertically with nvme drives and high core CPUs? single database on a very dense server should be able to handle stuffs not possible years back..so maybe not going partitioning/sharding route can be a viable option too?

Comment: Yes, you can. If performances are a concern you should do intensive tests..

Comment: "how were people doing this before JSON was supported?" Before JSON, there was hstore. Also, there was CSV, and 3x5 cards, and stone tablets.

Comment: @user_0 "For the same reason I would not use a big binary field or text. Also you must be careful with indexes" mind explaining this more...for the binary data, i plan to change the password from byte to text. but for the other comment, mind explaining or recommending better approach? i should not use text data type? open to all recommendations and critiques..thanks

Comment: @user_0 do you think this json route works when the key:value gets to like 50 fields? and like i said for a table like users table, we all know this gets updated often...so will receive lots of updates, maybe not much inserts but lots of updates..so thought when fields get to 50?

Comment: @uberrebu update is not a big deal. I mean, how much data will you update? Postgresql will work with 8kbyte block. You will use toast table, so I'll suggest, in ANY case, to stress test your DB before going in production.

Comment: `www.discourse.org` uses 1-1 relation between their users and user_options table, so seems i will be going with the 1-1 relationship. Reason why is because i can update the tables separately. I will rarely need to update using joins...only time i will use join is to select...1-1 is also a way to decentralize tables or a somewhat of a partition/shard because i can perform update son smaller separate tables that are related and spread the load across the different tables

Comment: am beginning to think of why postgresql? i am seriously considering mongodb now...sql databases not sure if have to be default anymore in today's age. imagine planning schema changes and doing migrations. I will think about this seriously..i also get TTL and so on that requires extra work with postgresql and app

Comment: If you need performance, PostgreSQL is better. There is a lot of debate, but for example: https://naiveskill.com/mongodb-vs-postgresql/

Answer (score 1):

With this solution you can avoid JSON. Drawback is that setting_value cannot be tailored to exact type you need, compared to your first idea.

For example you can create:

```
CREATE TABLE public.user_setting (
    user_id bigint NOT NULL,
    setting_name text NOT NULL,
    setting_value text NULL,
    CONSTRAINT user_setting_pk PRIMARY KEY (user_id,setting_name)
);

ALTER TABLE public.user_setting ADD CONSTRAINT user_setting_fk FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES public.users(id);
```

At this point I suggest you to have 2 query, one for users and one for settings:

```
SELECT *
FROM  user_setting us 
where user_id = 1;
```

Comment: this is similar to the `property bag` approach here https://www.culttt.com/2015/02/02/storing-user-settings-relational-database

Comment: Yep, nothing new under the sun...

Comment: i think i like the json approach better than this one..will like to take a more look at the JSON approach..but again will appreciate if you can post sources/references to big apps/companies using this approach or where it is discussed to be a good approach..thanks